# Smoothness of map of rings is preserved by base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

In stacks project, the ring map $R\rightarrow S$ is called [smooth](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00T1) if it is of finite presentation and the [naive cotangent complex](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00S0) $NL_{S/R}: I/I^2\xrightarrow{f}{\Omega}_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S$ is quasi-isomorphic to a finite projective $S$-module placed in degree $0$. So by looking at homology at dimension $0$ and $1$, this means $f$ is injective and $\text{coker}f$ is a finite projective $S$-module.

I want to learn the proof of [lemma 10.136.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00T4) which said that if $R\rightarrow S$ is smooth and $R'$ is a $R$ algebra, then $R'\rightarrow S'=R'\otimes S$ is smooth. At the bottom of the proof, I can't see why $NL(\alpha')$ is quasi-isomorphic to $S'\otimes_R\Omega_{S/R}$ from the commutative diagrm, I think this means an injectivity and $\Omega_{S'/R'}\cong S'\otimes_R\Omega_{S/R}$.

The injectivity is clear, right?

For the isomorphism, I think the coker of the upper horizontal map is $R'\otimes_R\Omega_{S/R}$, and the kernel of the lower horizontal map is $\Omega_{S'/R'}$, so this is a isomorphism of $R'$ module, tensor $S'$, we get a isomrophism of $S'$ module: $S'\otimes_R\Omega_{S/R}\rightarrow S'\otimes_{R'}\Omega_{S'/R'}$. I can't deduce $\Omega_{S'/R'}\cong S'\otimes_R\Omega_{S/R}$.

Where I am wrong?

Also, is this definition of smoothness of ring maps is standard? I haven't seen this definition anywhere else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the injectivity: the injectivity of the horizontal map upstairs comes from the injectivity of $I/I^2 \rightarrow \Omega_{R[\underline{x}]/R}\otimes_{R[\underline{x}]} S$ upon noting that the injection is split, hence the injectvity remains even after the base change $R'\otimes_R -$. Using this, one deduces that both the vertical maps are isomorphisms, as in the proof. Then the injectivity downstairs follows from the injectivity upstairs.

Regarding the base-change computing part: You don't need to do an additional base change: The point is that already one has $$\Omega_{S'/R'} \simeq R'\otimes_R\Omega_{S/R} \simeq S'\otimes_S\Omega_{S/R}.$$

For the first isomorphism, see [Tag 00RV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RV) (actually, it follows from the proof itself also). For the second, more generally one has
for any $S$-module $M$
$$S'\otimes_S M= (R'\otimes_R S)\otimes_S M \simeq R'\otimes_R(S\otimes_S M) \simeq R'\otimes_RM.$$
The reason why $\Omega_{S'/R'}=S'\otimes_{S}\Omega_{S/R}$ is explicitely mentioned is that this isomorphism shows that the cokernel of the map downstairs, which is $\Omega_{S'/R'},$ is projective as an $S'$-module.

Regarding the standardness: Maybe it's not standard to talk about the naive cotangent complex, but note that the condition for $R \rightarrow S$ to be smooth can be also restated as

> $S$ is of finite presentation over $R$ and the conormal sequence
> $$0 \rightarrow I/I^2 \rightarrow \Omega_{R[\underline{x}]/R}\otimes_{R[\underline{x}]}S \rightarrow \Omega_{S/R}\rightarrow 0$$
> is (exact on the left and) split-exact.

This is pretty close to saying "$R\rightarrow S$ is of finite presentation and formally smooth," which, in case this is still not the standard definition, it is at least standard characterization of smoothness.

Comment: Thanks very much for your attention for this question and your answer. The injection $A\rightarrow B$ is split, is this mean the map $0\rightarrow\text{ker}\rightarrow A\rightarrow B \rightarrow \text{coker}\rightarrow0$ is split? I have seen "split injection" in stacks project, but I haven't find the definition. In addition, could you explain more why [the right vertical map](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00T4) is an isomorphism? It looks like $A\otimes (B\otimes C)\cong(A\otimes B)\otimes(A\otimes C)$.

Comment: And the use of the commutative diagram is just to see the injectivity?

Comment: Since it is an injection there will be no kernel. So the exact sequence is $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow \mathrm{coker}\rightarrow 0$ and yes, the meaning is that this short exact sequence is split.

Comment: The vertical map is an isomorphim for reasons coming from [Tag 00RV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RV) again togehter with a formal maniplation such as the one upstairs. But perhaps an easier way to see it is invoking the explicit structure in this case: The module $\Omega_{R[\{x_i\}]/R}$ is a free $R[\{x_i\}]$-module with free basis given by $\mathrm{d}x_i$. The same is true for $R'$ in place of $R$, and so both the module upstairs and downstairs are free $S'$ modules on this basis. The vertical map is sending $\mathrm{d}x_i$ to $\mathrm{d}x_i$, so it is an isomorphism.